# How does node module cache work with factory function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, function

I am confused about how Node require cache works with factory function.

Suppose that I have two files, moduleA.js contains a Express route:

```js
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const { test, sideEffectA } = require('./moduleB.js');

router.get('/', async (req, res, next) => {
  console.log(test());
  console.log(sideEffectA);  
});
module.exports = router;
```

moduleB.js:

```js
let sideEffectA = 1;
const test = () => {
  let sideEffectB = 42;
  sideEffectA = sideEffectA + 1;
  sideEffectB = sideEffectB + 1;
  return {
    a: sideEffectA,
    sideEffectB
  }
};

module.exports = {
  test, sideEffectA
};
```

After I send three `GET` request to `/` I get the following results:

```
{ a: 2, sideEffectB: 43 }
1
{ a: 3, sideEffectB: 43 }
1
{ a: 4, sideEffectB: 43 }
1
```

The result of `sideEffectB` makes sense to me, because it is a factory function. But I don't understand why is `a` increasing with each request while `console.log(sideEffectA)` always get the same result `1`.
What exactly is happening when the router function is executed? Where does those two values `a` and `console.log(sideEffectA)` come from?

#### Update:

One more closely related question: if an async function is exported, will it only execute once with an resolved or rejected promise cached? Is there any diffence between

```js
const foo = (input) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  // Resolve or reject
}

module.exports = foo;
```

and

```js
const bar = async (input) => {
  // Something here
}

module.exports = bar;
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sideEffectA` in the `module.exports` statement is a primitive value, referenced by its variable name during [import](https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/getting-started/what-is-require/). When imported, a primitive JS number is assigned to `sideEffectA` in moduleA.js - a different variable to the closure in moduleB.js - which is why moduleB.js has incrementing `sideEffectA` values not mirrored in moduleA.js.

Comment: Thanks. I was thinking that primitives are something different from an Object. But how does the sharing / refencing work, exactly? For example, if an async function is exported, will it only be executed once with the resolved / rejected promise cached?

Comment: async means a function will `await` an asynchronous operation to finish before moving to the proceeding statement. Otherwise, the asynchronous operation is executed within the EventIO loop in the JS runtime. async functions are actually objects in "JS world", and they even used to have a reference to the textual statement definitions after being interpreted by the JS runtime.

Answer (score 0):

This behavior can be easily seen without modules or Node or express - just call `test` 3 times:

```js
let sideEffectA = 1;
const test = () => {
  let sideEffectB = 42;
  sideEffectA = sideEffectA + 1;
  sideEffectB = sideEffectB + 1;
  return {
    a: sideEffectA,
    sideEffectB
  }
};

console.log(test());
console.log(test());
console.log(test());
```

Every time you call `test`, you:

- Create a *new variable* `sideEffectB`, initialized to 42
- Increment the *outer* `sideEffectA` by 1
- Increment the *just initialized* `sideEffectB` by 1, to 43

So the `sideEffectB` in the returned object is always 43, and the `a` in the returned object changes every time the function is called again.

If you wanted the `sideEffectB` increment to persist, just declare it outside of the function, like `sideEffectA`.

The express router is simply calling the imported function every time a request is made. That is, whenever a client requests `/`, the following callback is executed:

```
async (req, res, next) => {
  console.log(testConfig());
  console.log(sideEffectA);  
}
```

resulting in the `test` function being called 3 times.

Comment: However, `console.log(sideEffectA)` stays at 1 after three requests.

Comment: The `console.log(testConfig());` will show the updated value because the object returned contains the incremented `sideEffectA`. But the value that's initially exported doesn't change - the `module.exports = { test, sideEffectA };` runs when `sideEffectA` is 1, so the imported `console.log(sideEffectA);` always logs 1

Comment: Nope. I have tried exporting an Object between modules. They always reflect changes in other modules, i.e. they are referencing the same Object